# Rewrite URL nginx remove hyphen

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

I am using this rewrite rule to redirect **http://example.com/a-b-c?id=learn-more** to

**http://example.com/abc?id=learnmore**

```
rewrite ^/a-b-c?id=learn-More http://example.com/abc?id=learnMore permanent
```

But its not working !! It does redirect to

http://example.com/abc?id=learn-more (learn-more is not converted to learnmore).

How to achieve this?

Comment: `rewrite` doesn't work with arguments.

Comment: Try to describe whole problem

Comment: I have a page at 

http://example.com/abc?id=learnMore

But I want when user visit 

http://example.com/a-b-c?id=learn-More (generated by SEO), he will be redirect to 
http://example.com/abc?id=learnMore (as you see hypen is removed)

Comment: Is it the only page you want to rewrite?

Comment: Yes , that would be cool

Answer (score 0):

```
location = /a-b-c {
    if ($arg_id = learn-More) {
        return 301 /abc?id=learnMore;
    }
}
```